# Need help with account setup, e-mail settings

Tags: evolution

I can't get my e-mail account (a free Tiscaly account) set up, following the video guide to enter some special settings. When I use a GMail account I created for this, it works very well indeed; most of the information was filled in automatically.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Ho [tradotto](http://askubuntu.com/posts/29233/revisions) la tua domanda. Si prega di notare che questo sito è solo in inglese.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to input Tiscali's server settings for IMAP, which can be found at http://www.kitz.co.uk/isp/isp_information.php?isp=tiscali under the Technical section along with your username and password.

For incoming mail, use: imap.tiscali.co.uk
For SMTP sending mail: smtp.tiscali.co.uk

I'm not sure what security settings (such as TLS etc.) are needed by Tiscali, so you might need to play around, or use Google to determine with which settings others have succeeded.

Hope that helps.